# zend studio in cloud connected mobile application create android application not working

Tags: php, android, zend-framework, mobile-application, zend-studio

I have developed one simple cloud connected mobile application. When I export this application to native application  I'm getting following error.

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDNgX.jpg)

```
Cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
Checking if platform "android" passes minimum requirements...
Checking Android requirements...
Running "android list target" (output to follow)
Available Android targets:
----------

id: 1 or "android-19"
     Name: Android 4.4
     Type: Platform
     API level: 19
     Revision: 1
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
     ABIs : armeabi-v7a

Error: Please install Android target 17 (the Android 4.2 SDK). Make sure you have the latest Android tools installed as well. Run `android` from your command-line to install/update any missing SDKs or tools.
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Zend Studio 11.0.2\plugins\com.zend.php.ccm.core.win32_11.0.2.v20140926-0202\resources\nodejs\node_modules\cordova\src\platform.js:268:42
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Zend Studio 11.0.2\plugins\com.zend.php.ccm.core.win32_11.0.2.v20140926-0202\resources\nodejs\node_modules\cordova\src\metadata\android_parser.js:54:17
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Zend Studio 11.0.2\plugins\com.zend.php.ccm.core.win32_11.0.2.v20140926-0202\resources\nodejs\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\shelljs\shell.js:1707:7
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:645:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:966:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
```

I have tried many solutions but I have no experience about zend studio and android sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install all versions of Android to function properly with Zend Studio 11. (not just the latest)

I would recommend you do the same, it's done in the SDK Manager. For Windows that's in:

Start > Android SDK Tools > SDK Manager.

Once open, select the Android version necessary (seems 4.2 by your error), install it, close and restart SDK Manager and Zend, should work!